# How to get read excel data into an array with python

Tags: python, excel, pandas

In the lab that I work in, we process a lot of data produced by a 96 well plate reader. I'm trying to write a script that will perform a few calculations and output a bar graph using matplotlib.

The problem is that the plate reader outputs data into a .xlsx file. I understand that some modules like pandas have a read_excel function, can you explain how I should go about reading the excel file and putting it into a dataframe?

Thanks

Data sample of a 24 well plate (for simplicity):

```
0.0868  0.0910  0.0912  0.0929  0.1082  0.1350
0.0466  0.0499  0.0367  0.0445  0.0480  0.0615
0.6998  0.8476  0.9605  0.0429  1.1092  0.0644
0.0970  0.0931  0.1090  0.1002  0.1265  0.1455
```

Comment: A sample of your `.xls` file will be helpfull

Comment: You can also have a look at the `xlrd` module - see http://www.python-excel.org - but yes, `pandas` will be a good choice if you're doing analysis work/plotting on the data - I suggest starting with the docs for [pandas.read_excel](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.io.excel.read_excel.html)

Comment: I edited in a sample of 24 well plate data, for simplicity's sake, I am using this data to test the code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This task is super easy in Pandas these days.

`import pandas as pd`

`df = pd.read_excel('file_name_here.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1')`

or

`df = pd.read_csv('file_name_here.csv')`

This returns a `pandas.DataFrame` object which is very powerful for performing operations by column, row, over an entire df, or over individual items with iterrows. Not to mention slicing in different ways.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I had to use `sheetname` instead of just `sheet`.

Answer (score 14):

I'm not exactly sure what you mean when you say array, but if you mean into a matrix, might you be looking for:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel([path here])
df.as_matrix()
```

This returns a numpy.ndarray type.

Comment: So given the data you just posted, this is exactly what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

There is awesome [`xlrd`](http://www.python-excel.org/) package with quick start example [here](http://www.lexicon.net/sjmachin/README.html).
You can just google it to find code snippets. I have never used `panda`'s `read_excel` function, but `xlrd` covers all my needs, and can offer even more, I believe.

Comment: I've heard a bit about that one, I'll look into it more thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could also try it with [my wrapper library](http://pyexcel.readthedocs.org/en/v0.1.4/capability.html), which uses xlrd as well:

```
import pyexcel as pe     # pip install pyexcel
import pyexcel.ext.xls   # pip install pyexcel-xls
your_matrix = pe.get_array(file_name=path_here) # done
```