# text extraction line splitting across multiple lines with python

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```
f = open('./dat.txt', 'r')
array = []
for line in f:
    # if "1\t\"Overall evaluation" in line:
    #   words = line.split("1\t\"Overall evaluation")
    #   print words[0]
    number = int(line.split(':')[1].strip('"\n'))
    print number
```

This is capable of grabbing the last int from my data, which looks like this:

```
299 1   "Overall evaluation: 3
Invite to interview: 3
Strength or novelty of the idea (1): 4
Strength or novelty of the idea (2): 3
Strength or novelty of the idea (3): 3
Use or provision of open data (1): 4
Use or provision of open data (2): 3
""Open by default"" (1): 2
""Open by default"" (2): 3
Value proposition and potential scale (1): 4
Value proposition and potential scale (2): 2
Market opportunity and timing (1): 4
Market opportunity and timing (2): 4
Triple bottom line impact (1): 4
Triple bottom line impact (2): 2
Triple bottom line impact (3): 2
Knowledge and skills of the team (1): 3
Knowledge and skills of the team (2): 4
Capacity to realise the idea (1): 4
Capacity to realise the idea (2): 3
Capacity to realise the idea (3): 4
Appropriateness of the budget to realise the idea: 3"
299 2   "Overall evaluation: 3
Invite to interview: 3
Strength or novelty of the idea (1): 3
Strength or novelty of the idea (2): 2
Strength or novelty of the idea (3): 4
Use or provision of open data (1): 4
Use or provision of open data (2): 3
""Open by default"" (1): 3
""Open by default"" (2): 2
Value proposition and potential scale (1): 4
Value proposition and potential scale (2): 3
Market opportunity and timing (1): 4
Market opportunity and timing (2): 3
Triple bottom line impact (1): 3
Triple bottom line impact (2): 2
Triple bottom line impact (3): 1
Knowledge and skills of the team (1): 4
Knowledge and skills of the team (2): 4
Capacity to realise the idea (1): 4
Capacity to realise the idea (2): 4
Capacity to realise the idea (3): 4
Appropriateness of the budget to realise the idea: 2"

364 1   "Overall evaluation: 3
Invite to interview: 3
...
```

I also need to grab the "record identifier" which in the above example would be `299` for the first two instances and then `364` for the next one.

The commented out code above, if I delete the last lines and just use it, as so:

```
f = open('./dat.txt', 'r')
array = []
for line in f:
    if "1\t\"Overall evaluation" in line:
        words = line.split("1\t\"Overall evaluation")
        print words[0]
    # number = int(line.split(':')[1].strip('"\n'))
    # print number
```

can grab the record identifiers.

but I'm having trouble putting the two together.

Ideally what I want is something like the following:

```
368

=2+3+3+3+4+3+2+3+2+3+2+3+2+3+2+3+2+4+3+2+3+2

=2+3+3+3+4+3+2+3+2+3+2+3+2+3+2+3+2+4+3+2+3+2
```

and so on for all records.

How can I combine the above two script components to achieve that?

Comment: You look like an experienced user, and should know that _that_ is not the way of treating data with Python. Instead, I recommend you to handle dictionaries.

Comment: looks can be deceiving. what do you mean?

Comment: I mean that that dat.txt file is not structured in a favourable way for you to parse it. You should try to get that (wherever you get it from) structured appropriately, for instance, as a dictionary, so the only thing you have to do is pass the key you want to have (the record identifier, you call it)

Comment: I know I am not solving your question but rather trying to help you out differently. Is that a data log you generate or do you receive it from outside the application?

Comment: It's from an excell spredsheet- I apprecaite your advice, but- right now I'm trying to solve it this way- I'm like- commited to the solution I started with- do you know what I mean? it would take too much mental effort to switch tracks right now

Comment: You might be able to get a Python data type out from an Excel file. Check this, for instance: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28774960/how-to-get-read-excel-data-into-an-array-with-python

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tips for reading in a complex file - Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28476946/tips-for-reading-in-a-complex-file-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex is the ticket. You can do it with two patterns. Something like this:

```
import re

with open('./dat.txt') as fin:
    for line in fin:
        ma = re.match(r'^(\d+) \d.+Overall evaluation', line)
        if ma:
            print("record identifier %r" % ma.group(1))
            continue
        ma = re.search(r': (\d+)$', line)
        if ma:
            print(ma.group(1))
            continue
        print("unrecognized line: %s" % line)
```

Note: The last print statement is not part of your requirements, but whenever I debug regex, I always add some sort of catchall to assist with debugging bad regex statements. Once I get my patterns straight, I remove the catchall.