# How to read data from an Excel file as 2 dimensional array?

Tags: python, pandas

I am looking for a good solution to read from an Excel file (*.xlsx) and put them into a 2 dimension array. I have already seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28774960/how-to-get-read-excel-data-into-an-array-with-python) and tried the below code.

```
import pandas as pd
psi = pd.read_excel ('./Psi130-130.xlsx') 
psi.as_matrix()
#psi
type(psi)
```

But, the last line gives me:

```
pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
```

So, if I have the below data on my Excel fie:

```
1 2 3 4
5 4 3 1 
2 3 4 6
```

Then my favorit output is:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4],
 [5, 4, 3, 1 ],
 [2, 3, 4, 6]]
```

Comment: you are not assigning it back. also use `.values` or `.to_numpy()` , `mat=psi.values` , `type(mat)`

Comment: Since the docs says `"This method is provided for backwards compatibility. Generally, it is recommended to use ‘.values’."` and `"Deprecated since version 0.23.0: Use DataFrame.values() instead."`

Comment: Thanks @anky_91 i assigned it back and it worked well for me.