# Reading Excel File as an Array in Python via Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

So basically I want to capture sheet as array.

Excel data[][]:
A  /  B  /  C //
D  /  E  /  F //
G  /  H  /  Z //

I want from code to return -----> **data[0][0]=A , data[2][1]=F** and etc.
Can you help me to achieve this via pandas in python.

Comment: It is not very clear what you expect. Have a look at [pandas.read_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get read excel data into an array with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28774960/how-to-get-read-excel-data-into-an-array-with-python)

Comment: So I basically want to make an array out of that sheet. And use that array in my code. It has to return my choose of cell like third row and second collumn----> [1][2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I achieved to solve this with numpy arrays , thanks to everyone.

Comment: I used Pandas first to get data template, then I convert it as numpy array.

Comment: this is my code while achieving this ;  ------->     import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_excel(r'location_of_excelfodler/excel_name.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet_name')
bdb=data.to_numpy()
print(bdb[0][1])